# NLP POS Tree understanding

Tags: nlp

How does tree gets formed in NLP -> parts of speech tagging. What is algorithm behind this? 
(S
   (NP Alice)
   (VP
      (V chased)
      (NP
         (Det the)
         (N rabbit))))

for instance how can Det "the" and N "rabbit" become NP (grouped under NP?)
What is algorithm behind tree formation and aggregation of nodes

Answer (score 4):

What you mean here is basically called parsing and not POS tagging. POS does only care about assigning the right POS tag to a word (I.e. DT to 'the' or NN to 'dog').

In parsing, this information is used to parse a sentence. There are dependency parsers and constituency parsers. Nice trees are generally drawn for constituent trees. In order to parse a sentence, you need a grammar.
A grammar consists of a set of rules which say how to build constituents. This is an example for a very simple grammar:

```
S -> NP VP
NP -> DT NN
VP -> V
```

This grammar would successfully parse the simple sentence

```
'the dog barks'
```

to

```
(S (NP (DT the) (NN dog)) (VP (V barks))))
```

There are a great deal of different parsing algorithms.
One of the simplest algorithms is the shift-reduce algorithm.
Then there are more elaborate algorithms like the CYK parser, the LL/LR parser. Furthermore, there is bottom-up and top-down parsing. I guess it is best if you do some basic reading here.
Here you find different algorithms:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Parsing_algorithms

A good introduction to parsing:
http://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_2nd_Edition/

Comment: This is a good answer and it was a good read. However, in future, please stop wishing the user all the best and thanking them at the end of your answers. You have been doing this consistently.

Comment: Thanks will read through. During Text mining do we consider only leaf nodes (tags made by POS tagger) and ignore group aggregate tags ("NP","VP"). Is this correct?

Comment: This depends very much on what you would like to extract from the text. Sometimes, it can make sense to look at constituents (for Named Entity Recognition (NER), for example, although NER basically is a preprocessing step in text mining.). You have to take care not to mix up terminology here.